# Azure Graph API to ADFS

Tags: azure, adfs, azure-ad-graph-api

Is it possible to use Azure AD graph APIs to perform CRUD operations on users managed in AD FS on premise? 
It could be achieved by mirroring users in azure AD or by using 'connect'. Is there any way this can be done without copying users to azure AD. Thanks..

Comment: I would like to know why you would want to do this? As Rick Rainey points out, it is not possible. If you tell your reasoning, we could suggest an approach.

Comment: Thanks.. I only needed a confirmation that this cant be achieved without using connect.. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot use Azure AD Graph API to perform CRUD operations on AD/ADFS.

There are .NET class libraries you can use to manage the *Windows Server* Active Directory.  These are in the `System.DirectoryServices` namespace as described [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt481534(v=vs.110).aspx).